# Как проверить заполнение вкладок QTabWidget циклом без визуального переключения вкладок

Tags: python, gui, pyqt, qtimer, qtabwidget

Ситуация следующая: в виджете `QTabWidget` динамически создаются вкладки, содержащие несколько полей `QLineEdit`. Вкладок может быть **`n`**-ое количество.

На каждой вкладке имеется одно поле `QLineEdit` - обязательное для заполнения (`self.tabWidget.currentWidget().lineEditType.text()`), если это поле не заполнить, то кнопка `self.buttonAdd` будет недоступна для нажатия. 
Проверка заполнения полей во всех вкладках происходит циклом по индексу вкладок "на лету", т.е. при каждом изменении содержимого поля `QLineEdit` с применением метода `QLineEdit.textChanged()`. 
При этом после каждого изменения содержимого обязательного поля вызывается метод проверки заполнения вкладок `def check_tabs(self)`, чтобы онлайн контролировать заполнение полей и активировать при надобности кнопку `self.buttonAdd`.

Если создать несколько вкладок (например три) и удалить содержимое, например средней вкладки, то начав её заполнять, вызовется функция проверки и автоматически откроется последняя вкладка и так будет происходить постоянно при каждом вводе символа. 
Пользователь не сможет отредактировать нужную ему вкладку без мучений.

Проблема заключается в том, что я никак не могу сделать так, чтобы либо вкладки не переключались, когда пользователь их редактирует, либо, чтобы цикл проверки запускался "под капотом" без видимого переключения проверяемых вкладок. И если какая-то из вкладок окажется не заполнена, то кнопка `self.buttonAdd` не активируется. Либо сделать так, чтобы после ввода первого символа далее проверка не запускалась. 
Метод `QLineEdit.editingFinished()` не подходит, т.к. он срабатывает после того как убран фокус с заполняемого поля.

Я пробовал уже делать с использованием словаря, куда записывал индексы вкладок и их текущее состояние (0 или 1), без использования цикла, но это приводило к тому, что каждая вкладка обрабатывалась независимо от остальных и, если я в одной вкладке очищу поле, кнопка станет неактивна, но зайдя в другую вкладку я изменю ее содержимое и кнопка снова станет активной, хотя другая вкладка так и останется пустой.

Может быть можно как-нибудь ходить по вкладкам (с помощью индексов например), чтобы GUI не видела этого (типа некоего бекэнда)?

Прошу помощи сообщества, спасибо.

Минимальный рабочий код:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.Qt import *


class TabPage_SO(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self.labelType = QLabel("№ типа", self)
        self.lineEditType = QLineEdit(self)
        self.lineEditType.setClearButtonEnabled(True)

        self.labelYearOfIssue = QLabel("Год выпуска *", self)
        self.spinBox = QSpinBox(self)
        self.spinBox.setCursor(QtGui.QCursor(QtCore.Qt.ArrowCursor))
        self.spinBox.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.spinBox.setMinimum(1917)
        self.spinBox.setMaximum(2060)
        self.spinBox.setProperty("value", 2020)

        self.labelSerialNumber = QLabel("Заводской №", self)
        self.lineEditSerialNumber = QLineEdit(self)
        self.lineEditSerialNumber.setClearButtonEnabled(True)

        self.labelSpecifications = QLabel("Характеристики", self)
        self.lineEditSpecifications = QLineEdit(self)
        self.lineEditSpecifications.setClearButtonEnabled(True)

        grid = QGridLayout(self)
        grid.addWidget(self.labelType, 0, 0)
        grid.addWidget(self.labelYearOfIssue, 0, 1)
        grid.addWidget(self.labelSerialNumber, 0, 2)
        grid.addWidget(self.lineEditType, 1, 0)
        grid.addWidget(self.spinBox, 1, 1)
        grid.addWidget(self.lineEditSerialNumber, 1, 2)
        grid.addWidget(self.labelSpecifications, 2, 0)
        grid.addWidget(self.lineEditSpecifications, 3, 0, 1, 3)
        grid.setRowStretch(4, 1)


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.centralWidget = QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralWidget)

        self.red_warning = "border-color: red; border-style: solid; border-width: 2px; font-weight: normal;"

        self.tableWidget = QTableWidget(0, 4)
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(
            ["№ типа", "Год выпуска *", "Заводской №", "Характеристики"])
        self.tableWidget.horizontalHeader().setSectionResizeMode(3, QHeaderView.Stretch)
        self.tableWidget.setSortingEnabled(True)
        self.tableWidget.setAlternatingRowColors(True)

        self.buttonAdd = QPushButton('Добавить из всех вкладок в таблицу')
        self.buttonAdd.clicked.connect(self.addRowTable)
        self.buttonDel = QPushButton('Удалить выбранную строку в таблице')
        self.buttonDel.clicked.connect(self.delRowTable)

        self.tabWidget = QTabWidget()
        self.tabWidget.setTabsClosable(True)
        count = self.tabWidget.count()
        self.nb = QToolButton(text="Добавить", autoRaise=True)
        self.nb.clicked.connect(self.new_tab)
        self.tabWidget.insertTab(count, QWidget(), "")
        self.tabWidget.tabBar().setTabButton(count, QTabBar.RightSide, self.nb)
        self.new_tab()
        self.tabWidget.tabCloseRequested.connect(self.closeTab_SO)

        self.button_activate()

        vbox = QGridLayout(self.centralWidget)
        vbox.addWidget(self.tabWidget, 0, 0, 1, 2)
        vbox.addWidget(self.tableWidget, 1, 0, 1, 2)
        vbox.addWidget(self.buttonAdd, 2, 0)
        vbox.addWidget(self.buttonDel, 2, 1)

    def new_tab(self):
        '''
        Создание нового ТАБа
        '''
        index = self.tabWidget.count() - 1
        self.tabWidget.insertTab(index, TabPage_SO(self), "Tab %d" % index)
        self.tabWidget.setCurrentIndex(index)
        self.nb.setEnabled(False)
        self.count = 0
        self.button_activate()

        self.tabWidget.currentWidget().lineEditType.textChanged.connect(self.check_tabs)
        self.tabWidget.currentWidget().lineEditSerialNumber.textChanged.connect(self.check_tabs)
        self.tabWidget.currentWidget().lineEditSpecifications.textChanged.connect(self.check_tabs)

    def closeTab_SO(self, currentIndex):
        '''
        Удаление ТАБов
        '''
        self.tabWidget.removeTab(currentIndex)
        self.tabWidget.setCurrentIndex(self.tabWidget.count() - 2)
        self.check_tabs()

    def addRowTable(self):
        for i in range(self.tabWidget.count()-1):
            self.tabWidget.setCurrentIndex(i)
            editType = self.tabWidget.currentWidget().lineEditType.text()
            spinYearOfIssue = str(self.tabWidget.currentWidget().spinBox.value())
            editSerialNumber = self.tabWidget.currentWidget().lineEditSerialNumber.text()
            editSpecifications = self.tabWidget.currentWidget().lineEditSpecifications.text()

            if not editType:
                msg = QMessageBox.information(self, 'Внимание', 'Заполните поле!')
                return
            self.tableWidget.setSortingEnabled(False)
            rows = self.tableWidget.rowCount()
            self.tableWidget.insertRow(rows)
            self.tableWidget.setItem(rows, 0, QTableWidgetItem(editType))
            self.tableWidget.setItem(rows, 1, QTableWidgetItem(spinYearOfIssue))
            self.tableWidget.setItem(rows, 2, QTableWidgetItem(editSerialNumber))
            self.tableWidget.setItem(rows, 3, QTableWidgetItem(editSpecifications))
            self.tableWidget.setSortingEnabled(True)

    def delRowTable(self):
        row = self.tableWidget.currentRow()
        if row == -1:
            msg = QMessageBox.information(self, 'Внимание', 'Выберите строку для удаления')
            return
        self.tableWidget.removeRow(row)

    def check_tabs(self):
        '''
        Проверка заполнения поля lineEditType и проход по всем вкладкам для проверки заполнения
        '''
        for i in range(self.tabWidget.count()-1):
            self.tabWidget.setCurrentIndex(i)
            if self.tabWidget.currentWidget().lineEditType.text() == '' or self.tabWidget.currentWidget().lineEditType.text().isspace():
                self.tabWidget.currentWidget().lineEditType.setStyleSheet(self.red_warning)
                self.nb.setEnabled(False)
                self.count = 0
                self.button_activate()
                return
            else:
                self.tabWidget.currentWidget().lineEditType.setStyleSheet('')
                self.nb.setEnabled(True)
                self.count = 1

        self.button_activate()


    def button_activate(self):
        '''
        Активация кнопки self.buttonAdd
        '''
        if self.count == 1:
            self.buttonAdd.setEnabled(True)
        else:
            self.buttonAdd.setEnabled(False)


qss = """
QLabel {
    font: 8pt "MS Shell Dlg 2";
}
QLineEdit {
    font: 12pt "Calibri";
}
QSpinBox {
    font: 12pt "Calibri";
}
"""


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setStyleSheet(qss)
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Из выше сказанного я увидел вашу задачу так.

По сути я просто добавил таймер, который переодический проверет то,
что вам надо. Интервал таймера (сейчас 1000 мс) установите по вашему разумению.

Я отметил для вас строки, в которые внес изменения.

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.Qt import *


class TabPage_SO(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self.labelType = QLabel("№ типа", self)
        
        self.lineEditType = QLineEdit(self)
        self.lineEditType.setClearButtonEnabled(True)

        self.labelYearOfIssue = QLabel("Год выпуска *", self)
        self.spinBox = QSpinBox(self)
        self.spinBox.setCursor(QtGui.QCursor(QtCore.Qt.ArrowCursor))
        self.spinBox.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.spinBox.setMinimum(1917)
        self.spinBox.setMaximum(2060)
        self.spinBox.setProperty("value", 2020)

        self.labelSerialNumber = QLabel("Заводской №", self)
        self.lineEditSerialNumber = QLineEdit(self)
        self.lineEditSerialNumber.setClearButtonEnabled(True)

        self.labelSpecifications = QLabel("Характеристики", self)
        self.lineEditSpecifications = QLineEdit(self)
        self.lineEditSpecifications.setClearButtonEnabled(True)

        grid = QGridLayout(self)
        grid.addWidget(self.labelType, 0, 0)
        grid.addWidget(self.labelYearOfIssue, 0, 1)
        grid.addWidget(self.labelSerialNumber, 0, 2)
        grid.addWidget(self.lineEditType, 1, 0)
        grid.addWidget(self.spinBox, 1, 1)
        grid.addWidget(self.lineEditSerialNumber, 1, 2)
        grid.addWidget(self.labelSpecifications, 2, 0)
        grid.addWidget(self.lineEditSpecifications, 3, 0, 1, 3)
        grid.setRowStretch(4, 1)


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.centralWidget = QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralWidget)

        self.red_warning = "border-color: red; border-style: solid; border-width: 2px; font-weight: normal;"

        self.tableWidget = QTableWidget(0, 4)
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(
            ["№ типа", "Год выпуска *", "Заводской №", "Характеристики"])
        self.tableWidget.horizontalHeader().setSectionResizeMode(3, QHeaderView.Stretch)
        self.tableWidget.setSortingEnabled(True)
        self.tableWidget.setAlternatingRowColors(True)

        self.buttonAdd = QPushButton('Добавить из всех вкладок в таблицу')
        self.buttonAdd.clicked.connect(self.addRowTable)
        self.buttonDel = QPushButton('Удалить выбранную строку в таблице')
        self.buttonDel.clicked.connect(self.delRowTable)

        self.tabWidget = QTabWidget()
        self.tabWidget.setTabsClosable(True)
        count = self.tabWidget.count()
        self.nb = QToolButton(text="Добавить", autoRaise=True)
        self.nb.clicked.connect(self.new_tab)
        self.tabWidget.insertTab(count, QWidget(), "")
        self.tabWidget.tabBar().setTabButton(count, QTabBar.RightSide, self.nb)
        self.new_tab()
        self.tabWidget.tabCloseRequested.connect(self.closeTab_SO)

# -        self.button_activate()

        vbox = QGridLayout(self.centralWidget)
        vbox.addWidget(self.tabWidget, 0, 0, 1, 2)
        vbox.addWidget(self.tableWidget, 1, 0, 1, 2)
        vbox.addWidget(self.buttonAdd, 2, 0)
        vbox.addWidget(self.buttonDel, 2, 1)
        
# +++ vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
        self.timer = QTimer()
        self.timer.setInterval(1000)
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.check_tabs)
        self.timer.start()
# +++ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^        

    def new_tab(self):
        ''' Создание нового ТАБа
        '''
        index = self.tabWidget.count() - 1
        
#        self.tabWidget.insertTab(index, TabPage_SO(self), "Tab %d" % index)
        tabPage_SO = TabPage_SO(self)                                       # +            
        self.tabWidget.insertTab(index, tabPage_SO, "Tab %d" % index)       # +
        
        self.tabWidget.setCurrentIndex(index)
        self.nb.setEnabled(False)
        self.count = 0
        self.button_activate(False)                                         # +++ False
###
#-        self.tabWidget.currentWidget().lineEditType.textChanged.connect(self.check_tabs)
#?        self.tabWidget.currentWidget().lineEditSerialNumber.textChanged.connect(self.check_tabs)
#?        self.tabWidget.currentWidget().lineEditSpecifications.textChanged.connect(self.check_tabs)

    def closeTab_SO(self, currentIndex):
        ''' Удаление ТАБов
        '''
        self.tabWidget.removeTab(currentIndex)
        self.tabWidget.setCurrentIndex(self.tabWidget.count() - 2)
#-        self.check_tabs()

    def addRowTable(self):
        for i in range(self.tabWidget.count()-1):
            self.tabWidget.setCurrentIndex(i)
            editType = self.tabWidget.currentWidget().lineEditType.text()
            spinYearOfIssue = str(self.tabWidget.currentWidget().spinBox.value())
            editSerialNumber = self.tabWidget.currentWidget().lineEditSerialNumber.text()
            editSpecifications = self.tabWidget.currentWidget().lineEditSpecifications.text()

            if not editType:
                msg = QMessageBox.information(self, 'Внимание', 'Заполните поле!')
                return
            self.tableWidget.setSortingEnabled(False)
            rows = self.tableWidget.rowCount()
            self.tableWidget.insertRow(rows)
            self.tableWidget.setItem(rows, 0, QTableWidgetItem(editType))
            self.tableWidget.setItem(rows, 1, QTableWidgetItem(spinYearOfIssue))
            self.tableWidget.setItem(rows, 2, QTableWidgetItem(editSerialNumber))
            self.tableWidget.setItem(rows, 3, QTableWidgetItem(editSpecifications))
            self.tableWidget.setSortingEnabled(True)

    def delRowTable(self):
        row = self.tableWidget.currentRow()
        if row == -1:
            msg = QMessageBox.information(self, 'Внимание', 'Выберите строку для удаления')
            return
        self.tableWidget.removeRow(row)

# !!!
    def check_tabs(self):
        '''
        Проверка заполнения поля lineEditType и проход по всем вкладкам для проверки заполнения
        '''
# +++ vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
        flag = True
        for i in range(self.tabWidget.count()-1):
            line_edit_type = self.tabWidget.widget(i).lineEditType.text()
            if not line_edit_type:
                flag = False
                self.nb.setEnabled(False)
                break
        if flag: self.nb.setEnabled(True)
        else: self.nb.setEnabled(False)
        self.button_activate(flag)
# +++ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        
        '''
        for i in range(self.tabWidget.count()-1):
            self.tabWidget.setCurrentIndex(i)
            if self.tabWidget.currentWidget().lineEditType.text() == '' or self.tabWidget.currentWidget().lineEditType.text().isspace():
                self.tabWidget.currentWidget().lineEditType.setStyleSheet(self.red_warning)
                self.nb.setEnabled(False)
                self.count = 0
                self.button_activate()
                return
            else:
                self.tabWidget.currentWidget().lineEditType.setStyleSheet('')
                self.nb.setEnabled(True)
                self.count = 1
        self.button_activate()
        '''

    def button_activate(self, flag):                                        # +++ flag  
        ''' Активация кнопки self.buttonAdd
        '''
        if flag:                                                            # flag 
            self.buttonAdd.setEnabled(True)                                 # показать
        else:
            self.buttonAdd.setEnabled(False)


qss = """
QLabel {
    font: 8pt "MS Shell Dlg 2";
}
QLineEdit {
    font: 12pt "Calibri";
}
QSpinBox {
    font: 12pt "Calibri";
}
"""


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setStyleSheet(qss)
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: спасибо! Отличное решение, в который раз уже выручаете меня! Я искал вот эту конструкцию: `self.tabWidget.widget(i).lineEditType.text()`.Именно это позволяет ходить по вкладкам циклом без визуального переключения вкладок!!!! Гениально!! Вы занимаетесь код-ревью?

Comment: @ВадимЛошкарев пожалуйста

Comment: @ВадимЛошкарев занимаюсь